# How to enter a PIPE character in Google Developer console using Safari?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I just wanted to follow the Google Compute Engine Quickstart tutorial, but I'm stuck, since I can't enter a pipe (|) into the console...

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the numeric keyboard using the equivalent to ascii-code, using the 'Alt' key + 124.